# How does mapping via Netbios work when the remote host has multiple drives?

Tags: windows, networking, netbios, net-use

Say i want to map a folder on a remote host on my device, for example

`net use Y: \\Server001\Videos`

So far so good, not a problem. But what i dont understand is, what happens if the remote host has multiple drives?
Say it has a C, D and E drive - how does Netbios specify which drive its looking at?

Comment: Windows can mount drives into folders. So all someone will see is one mapping with all the drives under it in folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMB file sharing (not NetBIOS) does not directly deal with drive-based paths in the first place.

Instead, the file server is usually configured to map a *share name* to a specific path, and it's that mapping which specifies both the drive and the folder. The share name has nothing to do with the folder name at all. (In your case, the share name is "Videos", and it could be located anywhere on the server – it could be "C:\Videos", but it could be "D:\Trash" or "E:\Storage\Movies".)

These assignments can be managed through `fsmgmt.msc`, or `net share`, or created through a folder's "Properties" window.

[image: Screenshot of the 'Shared Folders' tool on a Windows server]

---

As you discovered, Windows-based SMB servers generally have predefined shares for each drive letter. But these so-called "administrative shares" are *only* accessible if you have Administrator rights on the server, and might not even be enabled on some OS versions, so you should keep their use to the minimum.

It's better to define custom shares through a folder's "Properties" dialog or through `fsmgmt.msc`, as then you can select which users to give access to, and you can even move the folder elsewhere without any client noticing.

Note that the `$` suffix **does not** indicate a drive – it only makes the share *hidden*, i.e. SMB clients usually won't show it in share lists. The shares themselves are not really special.

Comment: Thanks, didnt knew most of that, i just mapped the direkt folder path now, should i generally avoid that and instead create a share$ folder on the server?

Comment: Yes, if it's for continuous use you should always create new shares. (Note that the `$` is not required and does not mean "disk"; it just means "hidden share".)

Answer (score 0):

Just had another idea that jumped into my mind that worked - i actually couldnt find that one through googling, so i might as well leave it here as an answer.

Drives in netbios seem to be indicated with a $, so the correct way was `Server001\C$\Videos`